How to exclude specific endpoint from CORS config in Spring Boot?
My goal is to exclude specific controller from general CORS configuration to narrow list of allowed addresses to the endpoint.
I have CORS configuration like this:
CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
configuration.setAllowedOrigins(of(
    "addr1",
    "addr2",
    "addr3"
));

So, all this addresses allowed to reach all my endpoints in app. I want to configure CORS in the way, that specific controller will reject requests from addr1, addr2, but addr3 will be still allowed to do requests.
I've added to that controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://addr3", "https://addr3"})
public SpecificControllerForAddr3 {

and removed addr3 from general config. But I still can reach endpoint from addr2 to this controller.
I assume this is not what I need, because general configuration still puts this controller to its basic CORS config.
How can I exclude this controller from general CORS config?

Filters are applied before controllers, so you can't overwrite a filter in a controller.
With Spring Security 6.2
If you want to use multiple CORS configurations, you have to use multiple security filter chains, see Spring Security Reference:

If you have more than one CorsConfigurationSource bean, Spring Security won’t automatically configure CORS support for you, that is because it cannot decide which one to use. If you want to specify different CorsConfigurationSource for each SecurityFilterChain, you can pass it directly into the .cors() DSL.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  @Order(0)
  public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
          .securityMatcher("/api/**")
          .cors((cors) -> cors
              .configurationSource(apiConfigurationSource())
          )
          ...
      return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public SecurityFilterChain myOtherFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
          .cors((cors) -> cors
              .configurationSource(myWebsiteConfigurationSource())
          )
          ...
      return http.build();
  }

  CorsConfigurationSource apiConfigurationSource() {
      CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
      configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://api.example.com"));
      configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
      UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
      source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
      return source;
  }

  CorsConfigurationSource myWebsiteConfigurationSource() {
      CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
      configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
      configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
      UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
      source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
      return source;
  }

}


Without Spring Security
You can use a fine-grained and global CORS configuration together, see Global Configuration:

Global Configuration
In addition to fine-grained, controller method level configuration, you probably want to define some global CORS configuration, too. You can set URL-based CorsConfiguration mappings individually on any HandlerMapping. Most applications, however, use the MVC Java configuration or the MVC XML namespace to do that.
[...]
To enable CORS in the MVC Java config, you can use the CorsRegistry callback, as the following example shows:
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

      registry.addMapping("/api/**")
          .allowedOrigins("https://domain2.com")
          .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
          .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
          .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
          .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);

      // Add more mappings...
  }
}



Thank you, so how do I specify which controllers will allow requests for the first cors config?
